# send emails in R on Linux

Tags: r, linux, email

I am running models in R on a Linux server and want the program to send me an email after the process is complete. Does anyone know how to do it? In Windows I use RDCOMClient to send emails via outlook; however, on Linux this option is not available.

Thank you.

Comment: I see 5 packages in CRAN that have "mail" in their names. The one I remember being discussed in the past is sendmailR.

Comment: Most of these deal with / overcome the fact that the _other_ OS generally does _not_ have mail setup.  Hence mail via GMail and whatnot.  Sending from Unix is / should be the very easiest case.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your Linux machine has email setup (which is very common and likely) then you almost surely have a command-line client for mail sending, possibly `mail` or `mailx`.

You can easily send mail by `pipe()`-ing into that process.  Or, if you will, by writing the mail file out and then using `system` on it.

Many mail readers like `mutt` can also be used to send. In general, "it depends". The lowest common denominator is the `sendmail` interface but that is very raw.